# Reporting error for specific device when handling query intent

Tags: response, actions-on-google, error-code, google-smart-home

I'm trying to implement an handler for the [query request](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#actiondevicesquery)

It's not clear to me what should be returned in case I'm not able to return the status of a device.

In particular I would like to understand how to reply if one of the devices in the query request is no more controlled/owned by the user.

Should I reply with an error response even if only one device of the query request is no more available? Or should I have to report anyway the state of the rest of the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an error in a specific device, you should return an `errorCode` as one of the properties in the response for that device. Alternatively, you can return `online: false`.

If you know that the device no longer exists, you may want to also run a [`REQUEST_SYNC`](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request-sync) call to refresh the user's devices.

Example:

```
{
  "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
  "payload": {
    "devices": {
      "123": {
        "errorCode": "deviceNotFound"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was expecting but documentation is not clear about how to report errors for specific devices.

Do you think it's really necessary to proactively  request sync?
I'm wondering if such error will automatically trigger a sync request.

Comment: I did notice the documentation was slightly vague about the errors per-device.

Sending this error will not automatically trigger a sync request, as it's not guaranteed the device is lost permanently. If you, as the Smart Home provider, know the device is gone, it is up to you to send that signal back to the Home Graph to trigger a sync.

Comment: yes it make sense that for some implementations not  finding a device could be a temporary error.
Thank you